# Aren't these random number generation in a range equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, random

Here are two of the variations to generate random integers within a `range (start, end)`:

method 1:

```
int rand = (int)(Math.random()*(end-start)+1)+start;
```

method 2:

```
Random numbergenerator = new Random();
int rand=numbergenerator.nextInt(end-start)+start;
```

Method 2 seems to work for me.

The reason I ask this: I was trying to debug my code and when I changed my random `int` generation to method 2, everything seem to work fine. Method 1 was giving unexpected results.

The unexpected results come from different post: but that is a distraction to this question
still it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694571/randomized-quick-sort-in-java-need-a-suble-fix). Here I replaced mehtod 1 with method 2 and everything worked fine.

so the question is are these methods of random int generation different.
method 1 I used has been upvoted in this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java)

What would be an example case where they both could differ (if they are different)?

Comment: How are the results unexpected?

Comment: Random numbers should be unexpected. That's the point.

Comment: "*What would be an example case where they both could differ (if they are different)*" you tell us! You observed the unexpected results!

Comment: `Math.random()` is equivalent to `Random.nextDouble()` not `Random.nextInt()`

Comment: Clarify (ie show or describe in detail) what "unexpected results" you're getting

Comment: @Eran: its not the actual numbers I talk about. but the range I of values I get out

Comment: @Bohemian: here is my another post where I used method 1 and had issues. replacing with method 2 fixed the issues.. look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694571/randomized-quick-sort-in-java-need-a-suble-fix

Comment: I think he means they are consistently skewed.

Comment: @MichaelT: please see my reply above to Bohemain

Comment: My guess is: casting to `(int)` truncates, it doesn't do rounding. So if `start = 0`, and `end = 1`, if the result of `Math.random()` is greater or equal to `0` and lesser than `1`, the value of that expression will be `0`. If and only if `Math.random()` returns exactly `1.0` will the result be `1`. DERP: `Math.random()` never returns `1.0`, so the first approach is just completely broken.

Comment: Moral of the story: when you're trying to generate an int, use the appropriate method, unless you know how to correctly slice the interval `[0.0, 1.0]` into equal-sized parts.

Comment: @millimoose: I followed this post for random integer generation within a range: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java

Comment: You have to explain what "unexpected results" means, as has already been asked.

Comment: @vanza: I edited the question above

Comment: @user1988876 You followed it wrong. You're missing a parenthesis around `(end-start)+1`. That is, the whole shebang should be `Math.random() * ((end - start) + 1)`. Operator precedence makes your code equivalent to `(Math.random() * (end - start)) + 1`. The idea is to make the **range** bigger by `1` to avoid the problem I described above. Not to add `1` to the result of getting a random number from a smaller range.

Comment: I strongly suggest actually drawing this on paper using a number axis that you "randomly" poke a pencil at to see what's going on. The way the algorithm works is that it picks a number greater or equal than `start`, and lesser than `end + 1`, then truncates it. If you don't make that range bigger, you obviously can never get a number greater than `end`, which truncated can never be equal to `end`. Moral of the story #2: don't blindly follow code snippets from the internet you don't understand.

Comment: @millimoose: thanks for catching up on my mistake. I will fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your unexpected results come [from a sorting algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694571/randomized-quick-sort-in-java-need-a-suble-fix), I suspect that by *unexpected* you mean it doesn't really sort numbers.

The problem is that the range of random numbers is not the same in both methods. The range in method 1 is `[start+1 , end]`, and in method 2 it is `[start, end-1]`.

So basically remove the `+1` part here:

```
int rand = (int)(Math.random()*(end-start)+1)+start;
```

so that the range is the usual `[start, end-1]`. I say *usual* because arrays are indexed in the range `[0, length-1]`.

Comment: that clarified it nicely. Thanks!